# append to variable in couchdb rewrite rule

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to create a rewrite rule, to read a view with keys that start with a string.

I can do this without the rewrite, but am struggling to do it with the rewrite.

## Access with direct query.

```
curl -g -H "Accept: application/json" \
    'http://127.0.0.3:80/bookmarks/_design/design/_view/webmarks-by-url?include_docs=true&reduce=false&startkey=["www.sciencemuseum.org.uk"]&endkey=["www.sciencemuseum.org.uk/\ufff0"]' | json_pp
```

## Then I try to do it with a rewrites.json

```
{
    "from": "bookmarks_by_url/:~name:",
    "to": "_view/webmarks-by-url",
    "query": {
        "reduce": "false",
        "include_docs": "true",
        "descending" : "false",
        "startkey": [":~name:"],
        "endkey": [":~name:\ufff0"]
    }       
},
```

What I want, but this is obviously not going to work. Is there a way to say this is the end of a variable? Or another way to write the rule?

```
{
    "from": "bookmarks_by_url/:~name:",
    "to": "_view/webmarks-by-url",
    "query": {
        "reduce": "false",
        "include_docs": "true",
        "descending" : "false",
        "startkey": [":~name:"],
        "endkey": [":~name:" + "\ufff0"]
    }       
},
```

---

The documentation for rewrite rules are terrible, If you know of better ones then please link.

Comment: If you are using Couch 2.1+, you may employ JS rewrites to use plain JS function for routing requests.

Comment: @ermouth can I combine the old json rewrites, with the new js rewrites?, or do I have to re-write my rewrites in js?

Comment: @ermoth you could move your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Couch 2.1+, you may employ [JS rewrites](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/ddoc/rewrites.html) to use plain JS function for request routing.

Having `.rewrites` section, containing a string representation of a router function, you can handle very complex routing. Moreover, you can even serve a response directly from rewrite function.

However, using JS rewrites you also have all JS query server penalties. They are:

- You add several ms to each request latency.
- Your rewrite fn is a single-threaded bottleneck, you can’t handle more requests than your rewrite fn is able to process.
- Since each JS engine instance in Couch has only 64Mb RAM for both compiled code and data, you can’t process large POST requests.
- All QS functions in Couch are hard to debug, rewrite is not an exception.
- You can’t use both old array syntax (which is waaay faster), and a function in one design doc.

Since I personally employ JS rewrite heavily, I can say pros are much heavier than cons. [There is an article](http://lesorub.pro/how-it-works) with some perf details related to JS rewrites.